# Filling a 2D list with name and family name

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, names

Trying to put a string with full names into a 2D list, I get an error list out of range, how can I fix it?

Example y[0][0] should contain "Charbel", and y[0][1] should contain "Daoud"...

```
string1 = "Charbel Daoud, Manuella Germanos, Anis Ismael"

x= string1.split(",")
print(x)

y = [][1]
i=0
for j in x:
        div = []
        div = j.split(" ")
        y[i][0] = div[0]
        y[i][1] = div[1]
        i+=1
    
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting an error because you were trying to index an empty list `y = [][1]`.

You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
[i.split(' ') for i in string1.split(', ')]
```

Output:

```
[['Charbel', 'Daoud'], ['Manuella', 'Germanos'], ['Anis', 'Ismael']]
```

Comment: Ok so if i want to add the names of another string i tried: y.append(i.split(' ') for i in string2.split(', '))    but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Use `extend` there rather than `append`.  `append` adds one single item; `extend` adds any number of items from an iterable.